# I just can't get my facade to work in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, facade

Please can some one tell me why my first home made facade doesn't work. I'm spending hours on this and I might be going mad.

composer.js contains

```
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/facades",
        "app/libraries",
        ....
```

/app/config/app.php contains

```
'providers' => array(
    ....
    'CloudsServiceProvider',
```

/libraries/Clouds.php

```
class Clouds {

    protected $_current = null;

    public function current() 
    {

        if($this->_current)
            return $this->_current;

        $this->_current = Cloud::find(1); // Cloud in a Model 

        return $this->_current;
    }

}
```

/libraries/CloudsServiceProvider.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class CloudsServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider 
{

    public function register()
    {

        $this->app->bind('Clouds', function()
        {
            return new Clouds();
        });
    }
}
```

/facades/CloudsFacade.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class Clouds extends Facade 
{

    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() 
    { 
        return 'Clouds'; 
    }

}
```

in the Terminal i do:

```
composer dump
```

When I call  $cloud = Clouds::current(); I get:

```
Non-static method Clouds::current() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context
```

App::make('Clouds')->current(); seems to work though.

I have followed a few tutorials but I just keep coming back to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You facade is using the same name of your Clouds class, you shoud change to:

```
class CloudsFacade extends Facade 
{
   ...
}
```

A tip: open your vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php, all 3 files **must** be listed there.

Also, you will have to namespace all 3 files:

```
<?php namespace App\Clouds;
```

Add to your providers:

```
'App\Clouds\CloudsServiceProvider',
```

And aliases:

```
'Clouds' => 'App\Clouds\CloudsFacade',
```

Then you

```
composer du
```

And you should be good to go.